# Unable to get ~/.dbt/ folder or profiles.yml file after installing Python 3.8 and dbt in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, installation, configuration, dbt

I am working on Windows 64-bit OS, x64-based processor

Python 3.8 is installed in below Path C:\Users*MyName*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38 which is downloaded and installed from “https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/python-3.8.5-amd64-webinstall.exe”

dbt is installed in CLI using below command

"pip install dbt"

After all these when i look for “~/.dbt/” folder or “profiles.yml” files
I am unable to find then anywhere

I am unable to find “~/.dbt/” directory under C://Users/MyName/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftEwr.png)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried running `dbt init` within the python environment yet?
I believe this is the trigger for the creation of those items.

(See docs here: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/init/)

Also - I dont believe there should be anything preventing you from just creating the directory and items yourself.

Contents for me are:

```
usr/.dbt
      | .user.yml
      | profiles.yml
```

Where the `.user.yml` file only contains an "id" string mapping.

And the `profiles.yml` contains the full layout of the documentation reference:

https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cli/configure-your-profile/

Info: Windows 10, Python 3.7.x

Answer (score 5):

Run `dbt debug --config-dir` to find out where dbt expects `profiles.yml` on your machine and then create that location including `profiles.yml` file.

Sample `profiles.yml` is available at https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cli/configure-your-profile/

Answer (score 0):

If you want profiles.yml to be created in the directory where you are running the project, use this code

```
dbt init --profiles-dir .
```